# Magento 2: Add new step in checkout under Reviews&Payments

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to add a new step in checkout step '**Reviews&Payments**'(like Apply discount code).

Please refer the screenshot.
http://i.prntscr.com/Gb4G60gFRfWbSl1uqFu4vA.png

I have tried many links, but getting added as a separate step. Please refer the screenshot.
http://i.prntscr.com/TvFf_G6LTFOjUawOBhmWgg.png

I want to display it under '**Reviews&Payments**' Step.

Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is possible but you could add a step before Reviews&Payments. Read [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) from the docs on how to do that.